# Why does type inference in scala only happen one parameter list a time?

Tags: scala

From [scala-lang.org](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/multiple-parameter-lists.html)

> It so happens that in Scala, type inference proceeds one parameter
> list at a time. Say you have the following method:
>
> ```
> def foldLeft1[A, B](as: List[A], b0: B, op: (B, A) => B) = ???
> ```
>
> Then you’d like to call it in the following way, but will find that it
> doesn’t compile:
>
> ```
> def notPossible = foldLeft1(numbers, 0, _ + _)
> ```
>
> you will have to call it like one of the below ways:
>
> ```
> def firstWay = foldLeft1[Int, Int](numbers, 0, _ + _)
> def secondWay = foldLeft1(numbers, 0, (a: Int, b: Int) => a + b)
> ```

Why was scala built this way? Wouldn't type inference between parameters be useful and possible?

Comment: Useful? Yes. Possible? Probably. Easy to do? I would guess no. Why it was built that way? Maybe for simplicity of the creators of the language that already had a lot to do by that time. Will never change? Yes and no, for **Scala 2** that will never be the case; but AFAIK **Scala 3** does provides better type inference that should work in this case.

Comment: [Here's a Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/55ThAxRORWipKh9hQLsKGA) demonstrating that what was `notPossible` in Scala 2 is `nowPossible` in Scala 3.

Comment: As the doc explains "it so happens" :)